# How to prevent "complete action using" while opening pdf file using Adobe Reader.

Tags: android, pdf, adobe

I want to open pdf file using installed adobe reader. I tried in the following way to prevent "Complete action using" menu.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(doc), "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```

Using the above code i managed to reduce the list size to 2. Is there any way to avoid showing context menu (Complete action using).

Thank you!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would like to thanks every one who tried to answer this question. After some browsing i found solution for my Question. which is perfectly working for me.

instead of using

```
intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");
```

I used

```
intent.setClassName("com.adobe.reader", "com.adobe.reader.AdobeReader");
```

don't forget to start activity in try catch block, it helps when adobe reader not installed on Device. Please check the below snippet.

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setClassName("com.adobe.reader", "com.adobe.reader.AdobeReader");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(doc), "application/pdf");
    startActivity(intent);

   } 
   catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityNotFoundException) {
    activityNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Android system automatically displays "complete action using" dialog box when two activities have same intent filter action. Once you select the default action. Android will not display it & complete the task using default action.

Comment: Thank you sunil, is there any way to select the default action programmatically

Comment: Please refrain from promoting your blog in your answers here. Bo has edited out the footer you were using, and we'd appreciate if you wouldn't do that again.