# Android setting default option to open pdf

Tags: android

I am opening a pdf document from my app. I have quickoffice and Acrobat reader on my tablet. Whenever I try to open the document, it shows me 3 options, qucioffice, acrobat and my app name (i don't know why it shows my app name). 
Can I set a default option to acrobat and get rid of the options ? I know, I can check the selection box to set a defalut option. Is there a way I can set it programatically ?

Thanks.

Comment: you can specify the intent's class to com.adobe.reader however if the user does not have the adobe reader an exception is thrown so you should catch and notify the user

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536143/how-to-prevent-complete-action-using-while-opening-pdf-file-using-adobe-reader/11561491#11561491, it may resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

> i don't know why it shows my app name

Perhaps you have an activity with an `<intent-filter>` that claims to be a PDF viewer.

> Can I set a default option to acrobat and get rid of the options ?

The user may not have Acrobat. The user may not want Acrobat. Please allow the user to choose which PDF viewer they want.

> I can check the selection box to set a defalut option. Is there a way I can set it programatically ?

No, you cannot. The *user* controls the *user's* device and the *user's* choice of PDF viewer, not you or any other app developer.

Comment: You answered my question! Thanks a bunch! BTW it's a lockdown tablet and I have complete control on it and that's the requirement. I don't want user to choose quickoffice and get access to internal storage. I guess, I don't have a choice in this matter. Appreciate your reply.

Comment: @sam: "BTW it's a lockdown tablet and I have complete control on it and that's the requirement" -- then why did you license and install QuickOffice, if you do not want it? "I don't want user to choose quickoffice and get access to internal storage" -- then why did you license and install QuickOffice, if you do not want it?